# Bootstrap Popover on SVG icon - Wrong Arrow Direction

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-popover

I have a bootstrap(v5.1) popover element placed on a svg icon. Popover element generates successfully but the arrow icon direction is wrong. Please see below for code; 
@create text & @modifytext are just text variables showing some dynamic content.

```
<svg height="20" width="20" data-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" title="Admin Info" data-bs-content="@createtext @modifytext" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info-circle" class="text-blue float-start svg-inline--fa fa-info-circle fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
  <path fill="currentColor" .......></path>                              
</svg>
```

[image]

As you can see the arrow is pointing in the wrong direction. How can I fix that issue ?

Comment: Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

## CSS Transform property

You could select your arrow and then say `transform: scaleX(-1);`
Like so:

```css
    svg {
        transform: scaleX(-1);
    }
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <svg height="20" width="20" data-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="right" title="Admin Info" data-bs-content="@createtext @modifytext" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="info-circle" class="text-blue float-start svg-inline--fa fa-info-circle fa-w-16" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
        <path fill="currentColor" .......></path>                              
    </svg>
```